# density plot for values in a specified column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, density-plot

For the following dataframe need to plot the density of (all) the values in the second column I need to use the column index (i.e. the number 2 to refer to the column) and not the column label.

```
Height  Weight Age
183       177   25
187       200   23
152       190   23
162       171   25
163       188   27
144       140   22
```

Had I been allowed to use column names I would have just done

```
df.Weight.plot.density(color='green')
```

but not sure how to plot one by using the column index.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
#Plot weight
print(df.columns)
df[df.columns[1]].plot.density(color='green') #using index-1
```

Prints:

```
Index(['Height', 'Weight', 'Age'], dtype='object')
```

[image]